# What was Sam saying in Van Helsing episode 11?

Tags: dialogue, van-helsing-tv

In Van Helsing S01E11, Sam was speaking in sign language but Mohamed would not translate what he was saying.

Could someone provide a translation to this please?

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to link the episode, but in episode 11 at about 30:30 Sam says something and Vanessa asks "what's he saying" with no answer. Also in the woods at about 32:00 there is considerable dialogue all without translations.

Answer (score 1):

He was trying to get Mohammed to spill his own secrets in a last effort attempt to save himself. Also, you're not supposed to know until the last episode what Sam is saying because it's a spoiler for the show's plot.

Comment: not for those who understand sign language though

Comment: And here my friend my search ends.